# Failure of canonical quantization of holonomic constraints

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, constrained-dynamics, quantization

I am curious to know why canonical quantization fails for systems with holonomic constraints (dependent only on the position canonical variable). When googling, I notice that there is a lot of literature that tackles dealing with non-holonomic constraints (e.g. path integral approach, dirac quantization).

However, for holonomic constraints, I cannot seem to find literature that tackles the problem directly as to why canonical quantisation is only consistent when using cartesian coordinates. Is there any literature that directly takles holonomic constraints?

Comment: I cannot think of any obvious obstructions to quantizing systems with holonomic constraints, but you do have to use the Dirac bracket instead of the regular Poisson bracket. The canonical reference is "Henneaux-Bunster, Quantization of gauge systems". See e.g. chapter 13.

Comment: You are asking for resources instead of an answer, but it's easy to see why canonical quantization can not be used naively when there are constraints. Suppose our constraint is $q^2=r^2$ with $r$ a c-number. Is $[p,q^2]$ equal to zero or to $-2i\hbar q$?

Comment: @octonion Yes, i understand that $[p, q^2] = [p, q \cdot q] = [p, q]q + q[p, q] = -i\hbar q -i\hbar q = - 2i\hbar q$ is not equal to $[p, q^2] = [p, r^2] = 0$. But i was more curious to find if there are any references that explains the UNDERLYING reason why we have these inconsistencies when doing quantization for such systems with holonomic constraints

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thanks i will take a look